# Can not connect to 802.1x no IPv4 is set although DHCP

Tags: internet-connection, ip

Can anybody please help me to setup my internet.

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Before the installation I was able to connect to the internet with the notebook.

I have to use 802.1x to connect.

I have no idea what to do anymore.

Somehow I don't have an IPv4 listed which could be the problem but why is this the case this worked before a install on linux mint 13 too..

```
joachim@joachim-TravelMate-5744:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for joachim: 
joachim-travelmate-5744   
description: Notebook
product: TravelMate 5744 (Calpella_CRB)
vendor: Acer
version: V1.06
serial: NXV5MEG00521605C8C7200
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: chassis=notebook family=Intel_Mobile sku=Calpella_CRB ...

*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: BA52_CP
   vendor: Acer
   physical id: 0
   version: Type2 - Board Version
   serial: Type2 - Board Serial Number
   slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Insyde Corp.
      physical id: 0
      version: V1.06
      date: 011/21/2011
      size: 1MiB
      capacity: 1984KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13flopp...

*-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 18
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns) [empty]
         physical id: 0
         serial: 00000000
         slot: DIMM0
         width: 8 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: EBJ41UF8BCS0-DJ-F
         vendor: ELPIDA
         physical id: 1
         serial: 5A341C9A
         slot: DIMM1
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 20
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz
      slot: U3E1
      size: 933MHz
      capacity: 4GHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae....
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
    *-cache:0
         description: L3 cache
         physical id: 21
         slot: L3 Cache
         size: 3MiB
         capacity: 3MiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 23
         slot: L2 Cache
         size: 512KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
    *-cache:2
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 24
         slot: L1 Cache
         size: 64KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-through instruction
 *-cache
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 22
      slot: L1 Cache
      size: 64KiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
      resources: irq:0
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:42 memory:d0000000-d03fffff...
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 06
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei latency=0
         resources: irq:41 memory:d0604000-d060400f
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:d060a000-d060a3ff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:d0600000-d0603fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=4096) m...
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=4096) mem...
       *-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 44:6d:57:18:37:b7
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
                          ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k 
                           driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic
                           firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
                           wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:17 memory:d0500000-d057ffff memory:d0b00000-d0b0ffff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=4096)...
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 01
            serial: e8:40:f2:c7:c1:71
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 
            tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 
            driverversion=3.121 duplex=half firmware=sb latency=0 link=no 
            multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:44 memory:d0400000-d040ffff
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:d0609000-d06093ff
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1e
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
         version: a5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         logical name: scsi1
         logical name: scsi4
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:40 ioport:2048(size=8) ioport:205c(size=4) 

        ioport:2040(size=8) ioport:2058(size=4) ioport:2020(size=32) 
           memory:d0608000-d06087ff
       *-disk
            description: ATA Disk
            product: TOSHIBA MK5059GS
            vendor: Toshiba
            physical id: 0
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/sda
            version: GN00
            serial: 32KIT194T
            size: 465GiB (500GB)
            capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
            configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00093e40
          *-volume:0
               description: EXT4 volume
               vendor: Linux
               physical id: 1
               bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
               logical name: /dev/sda1
               logical name: /
               version: 1.0
               serial: 32e0eda1-7f0d-49e3-b97a-177046053d7f
               size: 462GiB
               capacity: 462GiB

          *-volume:1
               description: Extended partition
               physical id: 2
               bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
               logical name: /dev/sda2
               size: 3763MiB
               capacity: 3763MiB
               capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
             *-logicalvolume
                  description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                  physical id: 5
                  logical name: /dev/sda5
                  capacity: 3763MiB
                  capabilities: nofs
       *-cdrom
            description: DVD-RAM writer
            product: DVD-RAM UJ8B0AW
            vendor: MATSHITA
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /dev/cdrw
            logical name: /dev/dvd
            logical name: /dev/dvdrw
            logical name: /dev/sr0
            version: 1.00
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
            configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:d0606000-d06060ff ioport:2000(size=32)
    *-generic
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
         resources: irq:21 memory:d0607000-d0607fff
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.1
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor QPI Physical 0
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.1
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor Reserved
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.2
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: Core Processor Reserved
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.3
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz

joachim@joachim-TravelMate-5744:~$ ifconfig -a

       eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:c7:c1:71  
      inet6 addr: fe80::ea40:f2ff:fec7:c171/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5819 (5.8 KB)  TX bytes:3524 (3.5 KB)
      Interrupt:17 

     lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:14144 (14.1 KB)  TX bytes:14144 (14.1 KB)

   wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:6d:57:18:37:b7  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 joachim@joachim-TravelMate-5744:~$ nm-tool

  NetworkManager Tool

  State: connecting

  - Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
 Driver:            tg3
  State:             connecting (configuring)
 Default:           no
 HW Address:        E8:40:F2:C7:C1:71

 Capabilities:
 Carrier Detect:  yes
 Speed:           10 Mb/s

Wired Properties
Carrier:         on


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
 HW Address:        44:6D:57:18:37:B7

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

Comment: What message do you get when you try to install. Have you tried plugging in via firewire and updating drivers?

Comment: I don't get any message. The credentials I have to use for the connection just show up to be entered/confirmed again, which would suggest that they are just wrong but they work on my windows computer. I updated ubuntu yesterday from another location where I don't need 802.1 security. So the drivers should not be the problem.